# htaccess rewrite with php pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

OK, first of let me just say I understand that this is a question that has been asked before. I just can't narrow it down to keywords and find what I'm looking for. So sorry in advance if this is a duplicate. htaccess rewrite is like black magic to me... I can't really get it to work.

To the question at hand:
I'm writing a simple barebone php/html site. I haven't done this in about 10 years (I usually use some CMS (wordpress, joomla etc.)). I'm trying to get a handle on some of the things that "come for free" with these CMSs. Like pretty URLs.
I have a simple index.php with some includes to build the pages. Then I have my includes folder with my dynamic content.

So two case examples of the actual URLs

index.php?page=index (my main page)
index.php?page=anotherpage (another page)

But what if I want to go to
index.php?page=a-sub-page-to-another-page

This is my PHP (index.php in web root folder)

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        $filename = "/includes/" . $page . ".php";
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            include("/includes/head.php");
            include("/includes/navbar.php");
            include $filename;
            include("/includes/footer.php");
        }else{
            include("/includes/404.php");
        }
    }else{
        include("/includes/head.php");
        include("/includes/navbar.php");
        include("/includes/index.php");
        include("/includes/footer.php");
    }
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

This works as long as I don't have any sub pages. But If I try to go to [root]/somepage/somsubpage then it doesn't work anymore. Can someone please help me out here? I'm looking to replicate the effect I get with standard CMSs like wordpress, where all URLs are SEO friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please! If anyone reads this... I'm still stuck on what to do... And I
>   can't find anything but mysql related articles. I've searched for
>   days. I just need to understand how to rewrite the PHP in my original
>   post to work with sub-pages, dynamically with variables. Ex.
>   index.php?page=index, index.php?page=secondPage,
>   index.php?page=secondPage&SubPage <-- this is the part I can't find
>   anything on. How do I get the php to look for more than one level
>   strings?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?level1=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/([^/])+$ index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\/([^/])+\/([^/])+$ index.php?level1=$1&level2=$2&level3=$3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

no in you php variable $_GET['page'] will have full url for example:

example.com/foo/barr

so $_GET['page'] => /foo/barr

However this is the first part only you would need do special function to map url to your page.

do SEO pages is to store do something like: example.com/some-url/of-my-special/page-in-here.1111.html so this is your url you make it as so you need to look at .xxxxx.html xxxx is variable so now if u write htaccess like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(\d+)\.html$ index.php?fullurl=$1&pageid=$2
```

$_GET['fullurl'] => /some-url/of-my-special/page-in-here.1111.html
$_GET['pageid'] => 1111

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  :)  Yes, I understand that the PHP Is the next part... But how? Now it only looks for a specific page. How to make it dynamic depending on sub pages?

Comment: this is really old topic: http://culttt.com/2011/11/16/how-to-make-vanity-urls-using-php-htaccess-and-mysql/
the iseast way to do SEO pages is to store do something like:
example.com/some-url/of-my-special/page-in-here.1111.html so this is your url you make it as so you need to look at .xxxxx.html xxxx is variable so now if u write htaccess like:
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(\d+)\.html$ index.php?fullurl=$1&pageid=$2

Comment: Ok, thank you again. However, I'm a little bit unclear as to how this translates into a dynamic naming structure? Will I have to do this for every sub page? There has to be a way to do this so it just reads the url and translates it?

Comment: Please! If anyone reads this... I'm still stuck on what to do... And I can't find anything but mysql related articles. I've searched for days. I just need to understand how to rewrite the PHP in my original post to work with sub-pages, dynamically with variables. Ex. index.php?page=index, index.php?page=secondPage, index.php?page=secondPage&SubPage <-- this is the part I can't find anything on. How do I get the php to look for more than one level strings?